# WPF Path TextBox with Browse Button as UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to make a very easy UserControl that has a path that you can type in a textbox or that you can find by clicking a browse button.
I tried to do this with a dependency property but this doesn't work completely when binding to it.

Here my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PathSelector.PathSelector"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PathSelector">
    <DockPanel Height="28">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="5" Margin="5 0 0 0"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Content="..."
                Click="BrowseButton_Click" />
        <Grid>
            <TextBox 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                x:Name="SelectedPathTxtBox"
                LostKeyboardFocus="SelectedPathTxtBox_LostKeyboardFocus" />
        </Grid>        
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And this is the codebehind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PathSelector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple input for path, with browse button
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PathSelector : UserControl
    {
        public PathSelector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SelectedPathTxtBox.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }  

        #region Dependency Properties

        public string SelectedPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedPathProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedPath", 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(PathSelector), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedPathChanged))
                {
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                    DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                });

        private static void SelectedPathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Changed!");
            // How to update the values here??
        }

        #endregion             

        private void SelectedPathTxtBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedPath = SelectedPathTxtBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this UserControl like this later:

```
<pathselector:PathSelector 
     SelectedPath="{Binding PathToSomeFile}"/>
```

"PathToSomeFile" is a string variable in the ViewModel that should be updated in both directions.

How can I achieve this? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `PathToSomeFile` is a field or property?

Comment: `PathToSomeFile` is a property in a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `SelectedPathChanged` as below:

```
private static void SelectedPathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((PathSelector)d).SelectedPathTxtBox.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("Changed!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **bind TextBox Text to your custom DP** which will automatically update its source property.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         x:Name="SelectedPathTxtBox"
         Text="{Binding SelectedPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                             Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

Also you **don't need to handle LostFocus**, since Text default `UpdateSourceTrigger` value is `LostFocus`. It will update the binding property `SelectedPath` on lost focus.

And since `SelectedPath`, default `UpdateSourceTrigger` value is `PropertyChanged`, it will update `PathToSomeFile` whenever property changes.

Comment: Just realized that I had to add `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` that both directions get updated

Comment: Text default `Mode` is `TwoWay`. And `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is needed in case you want to update source value on PropertyChanged. But as per your question, I thought you want it to be update on LostFocus. Anyway in case you want it to update on PropertyChanged simply set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Often it happens that I don't know the default values and set them that I know what the value really is. Because `TwoWay` is default it works without setting mode. But without the `UpdateSourceTrigger` it doesn't update when setting the Path with the Browse-Dialog. (Maybe because I just set the text property!?)

Comment: Yes, Milan's answer was the "real" solution (that worked). Your answer helped me to get some "cleaner" code. So thank you both :)

Comment: Glad to help joerg.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just miss the both direction part, you can use:

```
<pathselector:PathSelector SelectedPath="{Binding PathToSomeFile, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

More info here:

[`MSDN Binding.Mode Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have setup this by default with `BindsTwoWayByDefault = true`, in the register-method of the DP